# How do I properly import azure-maps-control into a Vue.js app?

Tags: vue.js, azure-maps

I'm trying to import and use the node module "azure-maps-control" in a Vue.js application but am getting an undefined error when trying to instantiate the map.

After installing `azure-maps-control` using npm, I've already tried a variety of ways to import the node module:

- Tried using `Vue.use(require('azure-maps-control'))`
- Tried importing in the Vue file itself `import atlas from azure-maps-control`

No matter how I import it, the atlas variable is always undefined when I try to instantiate the map. Here's some of the files in a fresh Vue.js app.

Main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(require('azure-maps-control'))

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id='myMap'/>
    <input value="text" type="button" v-on:click="initMap"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import atlas from 'azure-maps-control'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: () => ({
    map: null
  }),
  methods: {
    initMap() {
      this.map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                center: [-110, 50],
                zoom: 2,
                view: 'Auto',       
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: 'keyPlaceholder'
                }
            });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Ideally this would create a map displayed in the 'myMap' div, but `atlas` is undefined no matter how I import it. It's frustrating as well because I can see the suggested methods and classes when I make a call on atlas (atlas.Map()/atlas.HttpMarker()).

I'm relatively new to Vue and Azure Maps isn't widely used yet, can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: You might also be interested in this project: https://rickyruiz.github.io/vue-azure-maps/

Comment: I played around with that a couple days and while it worked fine, the functionality is just not there yet with that project. I believe it doesn't even support map markers yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found another Stack Overflow post on how to use Azure Maps with Angular and their import statemen: `import * as atlas from 'azure-maps-control'` and sure enough it worked like a charm.